# If I disable image viewing on a browser, does it still load from the server

Tags: browser, images

Most browsers allow us to disable showing of images. Now, does that imply the image will not be shown but brought from the server anyway, or it means the image wont even be requested in the first place. Perhaps the implementation is browser dependent.

I am interested to know about both PC and Mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the purpose of not showing images is occupying less bandwidth and speeding up network time.

Images won't be requested to the servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please point to some reference that would confirm this.

Comment: @Gunner: Why don't you try to search for it yourself?

Comment: @bubu: By doing google, we may end up getting links that may not contain accurate information. The SE community is very strong, therefore I would feel more comfortable with a link posted from someone here.

Comment: @Gunner: You can monitor HTTP requests with Wireshark. You will be able to notice it. If you find a browser that requests the images let me know.

Comment: @Gunner, then take our words for it. For most HTML renderer I have came across, if image display is disabled, it is not loaded. As @Benoit mentioned, these functions arises very long ago when people are still using modems and when bandwidth budget were tight (Not that it is not tight now, those days we are talking about MB & GBs, these days we're talking about TBs...)

Comment: Wireshark and Fiddler would let you know what you're pulling.

Comment: Besides, any even moderately popular, browser that actually downloads image while images are disabled would quickly be noticed by someone or other, and believe me, it would not go quietly unnoticed by the masses; the discoverer would blast it everywhere like Russinovich did with Sony, thus causing the browser devs to quickly fix it. (To be fair, there is *some* value in caching the images anyway; but most people clear their caches often enough that it wouldn't help most of the time.)